# What does "trapped" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "trapped" mean in this context ([from mini-ielts.com](http://mini-ielts.com/394/view-solution/reading/what-destroyed-the-civilisation-of-easter-island))?

> Diamond interprets them as power displays by rival chieftains who, **trapped** on a remote little island, lacked other ways of asserting their dominance.

Does it mean that rival chieftains were trapped on a remote little island, or that they trapped someone on a remote little island?

I am confused about the grammar here.

By the way what does ''rival chieftains'' mean??

Thank you so much??

Answer (score 3):

Imagine an island with 3 tribes on it, each of which has a leader, and they don't get on particularly well with each other.

The leaders would be rival chieftains.

Trapped, means they are stuck on the island together and so it looks like they find ways to up one another, as they have no other common enemy to unite them.